# Postgresql strange behavior with update trigger

Tags: postgresql

I have a `table1`: `id int, id_2 int, date timestamp, vec float[]`
And `table2` : `id int, vec float[]`

My target is to create trigger on update of `table1` which will take last 10 (by date) rows for `id_2`, take average of vectors by first axis(10 x N -> N) and write it to `table2` under `id` = `id_2`.

My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    BEGIN
        WITH rows AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT t1.id_2, t2.id, t2.vec, t2.date, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id_2 ORDER BY t2.date desc) AS counter
              FROM new_table AS t1 
              LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.id_2 = t2.id_2
        ),
        elements_average AS (
              SELECT id_2, AVG(unnest::float) AS av
              FROM rows,
              unnest(vec) with ORDINALITY
              WHERE counter < 11
              GROUP BY id_2, ORDINALITY
              ORDER BY ORDINALITY
        ),
        avr AS (
              SELECT id_2, array_agg(av::float) AS averages
              FROM elements_average
              GROUP BY id_2
        )
        UPDATE table2 SET vec = averages FROM avr WHERE table2.id = user_av.id_2;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$function$
;

CREATE TRIGGER foo_trigger AFTER
UPDATE
    ON
    public.table1 REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION foo()
```

The problem: when I update few rows in `table1` with different `id_2` in one transactions a value in `table2` becomes wrong. Not the average.
What's even more strange is that this code gives correct values in same situation:

```
...
        avr AS (
              SELECT id_2, array_agg(av::float) AS averages
              FROM elements_average
              GROUP BY id_2
        ),
        strange_thing AS (
              SELECT * from elements_average
        )
        UPDATE table2 SET vec = averages FROM avr WHERE table2.id = user_av.id_2;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$function$
;
```

So, small meaningless and unimportant `SELECT` changes the behavior of the function. Is it a bug of postgres or my fault?

Comment: What value in `table2` is incorrect? How is it incorrect?

Comment: Why maintain a table at all? Drop the table and create a view from the same query. Call the view `table2` if you desire.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it doesn't contain mean array. Something else with same size but different values inside, but manual recalculating gives another result.